# Sort by relationship value?

Tags: java, realm, realm-java

I have two model object classes that are related to each other:

```
class Car {

    private String model;

    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    // getter and setter methods

}
```

And:

```
class Manufacturer {

    private String name;

    // getter and setter methods

}
```

As you can see, the objects are related (each car has a manufacturer).

Now, in Realm, I need to get all cars, but sort them by their manufacturer's name. How can I sort by a relationship value?

Right now, all I have this:

```
RealmResults<Car> cars = realm.where(Car.class).findAll();
```

How can I sort this by the manufacturer's name, in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

You probably noticed, but `realm.where(Car.class).findAllSorted("manufacturer.name", Sort.ASCENDING)` (link sort) is not yet supported in Realm 2.3.x.

In your case, the simplest way to go about it would be to leverage the benefits of Realm being a no-SQL database, and just store the manufacturer name next to the manufacturer itself.

```
class Car {

    private String model;

    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    private String manufacturerName;

    public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        if(manufacturer == null) { 
           this.manufacturerName = null; // direct field access works since 0.88.0
        } else {
           this.manufacturerName = manufacturer.getName();
        }
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

}
```

And:

```
class Manufacturer {

    private String name;

    // getter and setter methods

}
```

Now you can do:

```
RealmResults<Car> cars = realm.where(Car.class)
                              .findAllSorted("manufacturerName", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Not sure why, but it's not working. Even though I copied and pasted it exactly as is.

Comment: It appears that it's assigning `null` to all of the `manufacturerName`s. Not sure why.

Comment: that is only possible if the `manufacturer` you set is `null` or their `name` is null; but it's also possible if you're using Realm 0.87.5 or older.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like as below,

```
   class MyComp implements Comparator<Manufacturer>
   {

    @Override
    public int compare(Manufacturer o1, Manufacturer o2) {
        // 
    // Compare the o1 properties with o2 properties
   }

}
```